# Can php redirection fail according to browser?

Tags: php, redirect

I wonder if a PHP redirection (`header('location: url.com'); die();`) is 100% reliable or according to the client's browser, the redirection may fail?

I'm asking this question, because we sometime see a message like:

> If your are not redirected in 10 seconds, click here

EDIT: should I display this kind of message for a PHP redirection?

Comment: Don't know about that but `header('url.com'); die();` is 100% reliable unless your code fails beforehand

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question but...
Redirects via header are immediate with the right command.

You need to set 'Location' and your url needs be valid ( with protocol like http/https ). See:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.url.com/');
exit;
?>
```

If you want to show:

> If your are not redirected in 10 seconds, click here

thats in client browser, should be a javascript with a timeout:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
document.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';
},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has nothing to do with the browser, all the browser can see is a redirect. Redirects work on all modern Browsers.My suggestion would be to add a redirect button when the script dies in case Something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Usually that sort of message would be a client-side redirect - perhaps only done in response to a message from the server indicating that a process has completed.

You can't do that with a server side redirect such as the one you've shown, AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Any redirection can fail, depends on the browser how it handles a redirection. Usually header redirection is given priority but what if browser prioritize the data instead of header's redirection. A php script writer can be stupid enough to send content with a redirect header.

The scripts that say "if you're not redirected in 10 seconds..." they're not using header based redirection, they are using javascript based redirection and browser can choose to reject it if it finds some security related problem with the script, or the tab with script may go to background and browser may choose to kill or pause the script resulting in a redirect failure.

Comment: I didn't get this sentence: "A php script writer can be stupid enough to send content with a redirect header.". What do you mean?

Comment: for example: header("Location: blablabla"); echo "this is a test";
some browsers redirect on header redirect, some receive the content "this is a test" first, and may or may not redirect after that